# Effect of temperature and surrounding medium in the Cavendish experiment to measure the gravitational constant

Tags: newtonian-gravity, experimental-physics

Would the results of the experiment change if surface roughness, temperature, pressure/vacuum in chamber etc. were modified?

[image]
(From *Sears and Zemansky's University Physics*)

Comment: What’s a gravity value?

Comment: Can you revisit the grammar in your question? We don't expect perfect English, but here it significantly hampers readibility; I can't really understand what "whether gravity value change generated between balls with respect to derived during Cavendish's experiment" means. I've tried to fix up the rest though.

Comment: Related meta post: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10806/

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. For example you mention surface roughness, but surface roughness of what? And why should surface roughness affect anything? There is no friction in this experiment. Also when you talk about pressure, are you thinking the experiment is in a sealed evacuated chamber?

Comment: Here, I said bigger balls surface roughness change from smooth to rough to have higher surface energy. Also, surface energy increases with  temperature. If experiment show different result we can conclude gravity depends on surface conditions also.

Comment: Surface energy??

Comment: Yes, it is thermodynamic propery of any physical surface. It is excess energy.